# Add OM element property from Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm using WSO2-Integration-Studio-7.2.0-linux-gtk-x86_64.
I want to add OM property to my sequence.

[image]

This is my configuration of OM element.
I want to add "<HeadElem>" as the value of this property.

How can I add this to properties?
I tried to add to value field. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the Integration Studio and will be fixed in future releases(https://github.com/wso2/integration-studio/pull/862). As a workaround, you can use the XML source view to save the config. Make sure not to change OM property-related settings from the Design view.
Sample config:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <api context="/HelloWorld" name="HelloWorld" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <resource methods="GET">
            <inSequence>
                <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                    <format>{"Hello":"World"}</format>
                    <args/>
                </payloadFactory>
                <respond/>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <property name="dadadasa" scope="default" type="OM">
                    <HeadElem/>
                </property>
            </outSequence>
            <faultSequence/>
        </resource>
    </api>
```